# Schema validation which allows field to be null or an object

Tags: testing, automation, karate

I'm having a JSON response from an API as per below:

```
[
  {
    "capacityId": "c34ac5c9-0bdb-496b-a7e0-17bc76009f3f",
    "requestBreakdown": [
      {
        "awbDetails": {
          "number": null,
          "date": "18042023",
          "weightInKg": 100,
          "awbStatus": "Pending",
          "bookingId": null
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "capacityId": "6d75b2ae-3f51-49d9-8e85-a29c310143bd",
    "requestBreakdown": [
      {
        "awbDetails": null
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

For the schema validation, in order to allow the `awbDetails` field to be null or an object, I had attempted the following:

1. Using #null

`awbDetails: '#null #(awbDetailsSchema)'`

But, it gives the following error:

```
>>> failed features:
java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

2. Using double hash ##

`awbDetails: '##(awbDetailsSchema)'`

But, it gives the following error:

```
>>> failed features:
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

I had also went through the documentation https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#schema-validation but couldn't find a solution.

I'm new to Karate and I would really appreciate if someone can shed some lights on this.

Karate version: v1.3.0

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a really complex schema validation in my opinion and I would split it into a few steps:

```
* def awbDetails = ({ number: null, date: '#string', weightInKg: '#number', awbStatus: '#string', bookingId: '##string' })
* def requestItem = ({ awbDetails: '##(awbDetails)' })
* def responseItem = { capacityId: '#string', requestBreakdown: '#[] requestItem' }
```

And then this one-liner would work on the response you provided:

```
* match each response == responseItem
```

Please refer this section of the docs for why the round brackets are needed: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate#remove-if-null